# How to make relation between rows in the same table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Let me show an example first:

Table1:
id | sub_is | name
---|--------|-----
1   | null    | group 1
2   | 1        | group 2
3   | 1        | group 3
4   | 2        | group 4
5   | 2        | group 5
6   | 3        | group 6
7   | 1        | group 7
8   | 4        | group 8

It will be look like a small structure:

> group 1
> |- group 2
> |     |-group 4
> |     |     |-hroup 8
> |     |-group 5
> |- group 3
> |     |-group 6
> |- group 7

My question is: 
How can I do this in Django?
How, if it is possible, I can make relation between two rows in the same table?

Thanks for any suggestions and any help.

---

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
class Department(models.Model):
sub_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This way I cannot call the field with the name of the class I'm in.

Comment: Can you share your model? This is possible with recursive ForeignKey

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this will help you**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.ManyToManyField(Child, related_name="bar")
  baz = models.ManyToManyField(Child, related_name="baz")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).